# Mybatis returning different class T

Tags: java, mybatis

I would like to know if there's any way that I can make `Mybatis` Interface return different class.
I'am using `@SelectProvider` to create the sql;

It would be like next:

```
public interface DaoTemplate<T extends Common> {

  @SelectProvider(method = "findById", type = DaoTemplateImpl.class)
  public T findfindById(T bean);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the requirement, it looks like something I have done for my app:

I have defined a common generic mapper interface:

`public interface DataMapper<F, D> {
    List<D> list(@Param("filter") F filter);
    D getById(@Param("filter") F filter);`

Then the "concrete" mapper does not need to declare the methods:
`public interface OrderMapper extends DataMapper<OrderFilter, OrderDto> {}`

But The SQL is defined in XML files (1 for each concrete mapper), cannot be done in `@Select` or `@SelectProvider` annotations because the SQL has to change for each type, and variable cannot be used because annotation property values are resolved on compile time.